# Having trouble with PHP Laravel 8 array

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code

```
$dataSet = [];
        foreach ($answers as $index => $answer) {
            $dataSet[] = [$answer->formfield => $answer->answer];
        }
        dd($dataSet);
```

Here is how it looks:

```
array:14 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "BC_NC_USCIS_NAME1" => "KIMBERLY JAX SMITH"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "Birth_name_styled_in_upper_case_lower_case" => "Kimberly Jax Smith"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "Name_of_the_Trust_2" => "KJSmith, LLC."
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "FIRST_NAME_MIDDLE_INITIAL_LAST_NAME3" => "KIMBERLY J SMITH"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▶]
  5 => array:1 [▶]
  6 => array:1 [▶]
  7 => array:1 [▶]
  8 => array:1 [▶]
  9 => array:1 [▶]
  10 => array:1 [▶]
  11 => array:1 [▶]
  12 => array:1 [▶]
  13 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Here is what I need it to look like

```
array:8 [▼
  "BC_NC_USCIS_NAME1" => "David"
  "FIRST_NAME_MIDDLE_INITIAL_LAST_NAME1" => "Patrick"
  "LAST_NAME_FIRST_NAME_MIDDLE_NAME_1" => "Smith"
  "Current_Address" => "2042 E Quince St"
  "Birth_name_styled_in_upper_case_lower_case" => "DAVID PATRICK SMITH"
  "Current_City" => "Mesa"
  "Current_State" => "AZ"
  "Current_Zip_Code" => "85213"
]
```

Please help if you can! I am banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the following and assign value to the particular key instead of array.

```
$dataSet = [];
    foreach ($answers as $index => $answer) {
        $dataSet[$answer->formfield] = $answer->answer;
    }
dd($dataSet);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `pluck` functionality that Collections offer (as this is exactly what `pluck` is for). If `$answers` is a Collection:

```
$answers->pluck('answer', 'formfield')
```

If `$answers` is an array then make a Collection from that array:

```
collect($answers)->pluck('answer', 'formfield')
```

That would give you a list that is keyed by 'formfield' with the values being the value of the 'answer' property/attribute.

If you want an array from the Collection just call `toArray()` on the Collection.

Also, `pluck` exists on Query Builder, so you can get your list from the database directly if that is where that data had come from:

```
DB::table(...)...->pluck('answer', 'formfield')
```

Or via Eloquent:

```
Model::...->pluck('answer', 'formfield')
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) - `pluck`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-toarray) - `toArray`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Database: Query Builder - Retrieving A List Of Column Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-list-of-column-values) `pluck`